# Kivy Actionbar on_previous

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I am trying to use the on_previous event for the actionbar in Kivy, but it won't call the function I bind to it.

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
ActionBar:
    on_previous: test()
    pos_hint: {'top':1}
    ActionView:
        use_separator: True
        ActionPrevious:
            title: 'Action Bar'
            with_previous: True
'''))
def test():
    print "Hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the actual problem? If you find something 'won't call the function' or similar, you should paste the error traceback which gives information about the problem.

In this case, I guess the problem is that your test function isn't in the kv namespace. You could import it with the `#:import` command in kv, or often it is easier to make these things methods of (for instance) your App class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Register>:
  ActionBar:
    pos_hint: {'top':1}
    ActionView:
        use_separator: True
        separator_width: 5
        ActionPrevious:
            title: "Student Registration"
            markup: True
            color: 255,255,0,0.9
            with_previous: True
            on_release: root.Onpre()
```

on register class:

```
def Onpre(self):
    self.ids.'screen manager id'.current = 'screen to return'
```